# Weird results when trying to get UI elements to fit a dynamic size in Unity

Tags: layout, unity-game-engine

I have a system where if you walk by a sign it will create a popup dialogue which is fine (just the popup part) but when I try to make it to where it can be adjusted based on how much text is displayed (Content Size Fitter) then I get something that literally does not make any sense to me whatsoever.  When using World Space my font on Text components has to be 0 (also makes no sense) so that 1 letter isn't the size of 100 units and the combination of these 2 issues has almost made me go mad but that is the reason why I am here so you all can save me!

My setup for my sign :

[image]
[image]

Now this is the dialogue that is spawned viewed from the inspector (Not shown in the scene/game view yet) :

[image]
[image]

Now this is when the player walks near the sign with all the components you see in the screenshots :

[image]

As you can see the height of my dialoguePanel for some reason keeps going to 321 and New Years isn't close so this countdown I am not happy with.  It should be adjusting to how much text is in it.  I mean I just did a tooltip almost 100% identical except that the Canvas isn't World Space but Screen Space - Overlay.  On top of all this it seems any text I use in World Space HAS to be font 0.  Please help I am about to lose my mind.

Comment: You MUST use

"Screen space overlay"

and you MUST use

"Scale with screen size"

it's just that simple. The other options

Are not available and don't work.

It's just that simple, there's nothing else to it.

It's just one of those funny things about Unity that they accidentally made the defaults to other settings (which do not work).

Comment: @JoeBlow http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

World space canvas is a bit tricky. And guess what is even more tricky: content size fitter. One of solutions is that you add your dialog UI element manually in the scene at desired location and tweak its `RectTransform` values in inspector to get what you want to see in scene view and then save it as prefab.

Read more about [How Content Size Fitter works](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIFitContentSize.html) and there is one more thing about UI when working with world space canvas. **UI is way too bigger than your other scene elements.** To solve this problem you have to scale it down as instructed in section [Specify the size of the Canvas in the world](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html).

Hope it helps :)